# How to pass a true/false value to my angular app when it gets bootstrapped?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a angularjs app that I startup in a view in my ASP.NET MVC app.

**View page:**

```
<div ng-app="userApp">
    <div ng-view ng-cloak></div>
</div>


<script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
    var userApp = angular.module("userApp", ["ngRoute", "ngSanatize"])
        .configi(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                controller: "userController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "../user/index.html"
            });
        });
})();
```

I need to pass a true/false value to my angular app like so I can reference that from inside my application.

Given what I have now, what is the best way to do this?

In my ASP.NET view page I have access to this value like:

```
<%= Model.IsProd %>
```

Comment: where you want to use true/false?

Comment: @RahulSharma in my userController.  Like:  ```vm.IsProd = true;```

Comment: Can you use an `<input type='hidden'>` element?

Answer (score 0):

**To inject into your app:**

```
(function () {
    var isProd = '<%= Model.IsProd %>';
    var userApp = angular.module("userApp", ["ngRoute", "ngSanatize"])
        .value("isProd", isProd)
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "userController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "../user/index.html"
        });
    });
})();
```

**To inject into your controllers:**

```
module.controller("SomeController", function($scope, isProd) {
    $scope.isProd = isProd;
});
```

Comment: I can't do that in my app.js file as it isn't a ASP.NET view page, my view page in my Q above just has the html with ng-app etc.   Can I do something there?

Comment: I've edited, can you check it out and see if it works for you?

Comment: No that' won't work, I can only do ```<%= Model.IsProd %>``` in the view page, not in a .js file like you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `globalIsProd` variable at view page before angularjs `<scripts>`:

```
<script>
   var globalIsProd = '@Model.IsProd' == 'True' ? true : false;
</script>
```

and use it at your controller:

```
.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.isProd = globalIsProd;
});
```